# Using Bundle in an activity in Android

Tags: android

I have an intermittent issue in using bundle. I have created a widget and when the user clicks widget the widget opens the mainscreen and get the bundle value from there.  This part is working fine without any issue.

The problem is when I open the mainActivity screen directly (By clicking the icon in the homescreen) I am getting a nullPointerException in the place where I have declared bundle. Once I get the error I am not able to open the app unless I force stop or clear the data.

The same code is working fine on Samsung S3 running 4.3, Nexus one, Galaxy Nexus too. I am getting this issue in KitKat 4.4.4..

I am not sure why this going inside the bundle when I haven't put anything in the bundle. Here is what I have done in MainActivity

```
 Bundle bundle =  getIntent().getExtras();
 if(bundle != null)  
 {
String callFromWidget = bundle.getString("callFromWidget");
Log.e("!null","Why is it coming inside the bundle " +callFromWidget);

if(callFromWidget.equalsIgnoreCase(res.getString(R.string.widget)))
{
      //do something
    }
 }
 else
 {

     //Update database there is nothing from bundle

 }
```

Here is the logs:

```
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/!null(7251): Why is it coming inside the bundle null
06-27 15:55:26.824: D/AndroidRuntime(7251): Shutting down VM
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251): Process: com.vkv.ProjectB, PID: 7251
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vkv.ProjectB/com.vkv.ProjectB.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at com.vkv.ProjectB.Main.onCreate(Main.java:218)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
06-27 15:55:26.824: E/AndroidRuntime(7251):     ... 9 more
```

Comment: are you sure passing string in **bundle key of "callFromWidget";** ?

Comment: are you passing boolean or string value

Comment: The real question is, does the Intent have a Extras Bundle parameter even if it's empty? And the answer is probably yes, so you should be null-checking the result of the getString and not just the extras bundle.

Comment: @CapDroid - Yes. The problem is not passing value in bundle the problem is when I open the main screen directly without the widget I get this issue

Comment: @Giridharan I am passing String value and checking with it.

Comment: @Zhuinden I didn't understand what are you trying to say? When there is no bundle request why isn't not null?

Comment: @TheDevMan show your full source code

Comment: Which part of the code?

Comment: How come it is working in other phones? Not on my Nexus 5

Comment: callFromWidget is null, handle that

Comment: i know it is null.. i don't understand why should it get into the bundle first place because the bundle will be null and according to the condition it should get to else part.

Comment: It is not necesary to be nul... if you pass some other parameter

    intent.putExtra("somerandomstuff","hey"); 

in the intent, then the bundle will not be null, while the extra callFromWidget will be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(callFromWidget)) {
    //    Apply your code
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue, but still I am surprised why would it go inside the Bundle as I have given the condition if bundle != null and I haven't sent any bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the Activity from the Widget you use the PendingIntent with your provided Bundle, which contains the desired String. But if you don't call the Activity this way another Intent is used, which doesn't contains the Bundle.

Hence, in this line

```
String callFromWidget = bundle.getString("callFromWidget");
```

null is passed to the String and that's why you get a NPE in your if-clause.

Check callFromWidget for null and the exception should be gone.

```
Bundle bundle =  getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null) {

    String callFromWidget = bundle.getString("callFromWidget");
    Log.e("!null","Why is it coming inside the bundle " +callFromWidget);

    if(callFromWidget != null && callFromWidget.equalsIgnoreCase(res.getString(R.string.widget))) {
         //do something
    } else {
        //Update database there is nothing from bundle
    }
}
```

Comment: But How come it is working fine in S3 and other phones

Comment: That would be a good question to the Google forums. I just can provide a workaround based on your snippet.

Comment: Even after I am still getting if(callFromWidget != null && callFromWidget.equalsIgnoreCase(res.getString(R.string.widget))) the same problem.